# Optimize Joins (more than 2 tables, where filter)

Tags: sql, database, sybase

Couple of Sybase database query questions:

1. If I do an join and have a where clause, would the filter be applied prior to the actual join? In other words, is it faster than join without any where conditions?
2. I have an example involving 3 tables (with columns listed below):

   ```
   A: O1,....
   B: E1,E2,...
   C: O1, E2, E2
   ```

So my join looks like:

```
select A.*, B* from B,C,A
where 
C.E1=B.E1 and C.E2=B.E2 and C.O1=A.O1 
and A.O2 in (...)
and B.E3 in (...)
```

Would my joins be any significantly faster if I eliminated C and added O1 to table B instead?

```
B:E1,E2,O1....
```

Comment: I think we need to understand a little more about what your relationships actually represent.  Technically, yes, your `JOIN`s would be faster if you removed `C` from the query.  However, this can be counter-productive if you start violating good normalization practices (so, it depends).  Don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), always explicitly qualify your `JOIN`s - that's been the recommendation for 20 years.  _Some_ RDBMSs are smart enough to turn this kind of thing into regular joins, but I don't know about Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use proper join syntax:

```
select A.*, B.*
from B join C
     on C.E1=B.E1 and C.E2=B.E2 join
     A
     on C.O1=A.O1
where B.E3 in (...)
```

The "," means cross join and it is prone to problems since it is easily missed.  Your query becomes much different if you say "from B C, A".  Also, it gives you access to outer joins, and makes the statement much more readable.

The answer to your question is "yes".  Your query will run faster if there are fewer tables being joined.  If you are doing a join on a primary key, and the tables fit into memory, then the join is not expensive.  However, it is still faster to just find the data in the record in B.

As I say this, there could be some boundary cases in some databases where this is not necessarily true.  For instance, if there is only one value in the column, and the column is a long string, then adding the column onto pages could increase the number of pages needed for B.  Such extreme cases are unlikely, and you should see performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Speed will generally depends on number or rows the SQL Server has to read.

1. I don't think it makes any difference using a where clause or a join
2. Depends .. on how many rows are in the eliminated table

It can depend on the order you add the joins or where clauses in, e.g. if there are only a few rows in C, and you add that first as a table or where, it immediately cuts down on the number of matches that are possible in.  If, however there are millions of rows in C, then you have to read millions to find the matches.

Modern optimizers can rearrange your query to be more efficient but dont rely on it.

What can really cut down the number of rows read is adding indexes to the join columns - if you have an index on A.O1 AND  on C.O1 then it can cut down massivley on the number of reads.